# Choosing a model for input: categorised, weighted sequence, output: binary variable

Tags: markov-process, recurrent-neural-network, word-embeddings, sequence-analysis, language-models

What would be an appropriate model for predicting a binary target variable, given a weighted sequence?

Sequences will be reasonably short, typically between ~ 1 and 5 elements. I have in the order of 200,000 examples for training and testing.

Illustrated example

Say I have the following categories: A, B, C, D.

Each category can have a weight between zero and one.

Example sequences:

- A (0.33), B (0.71), C (0.0), D (0.95) ⇒ 1
- C (0.21), A (0.67) ⇒ 0
- B (0.5), D (1) ⇒ 1
- B (0.2), D (0.6) ⇒ 0
- C (0.3) A (0.6), B (0.2)  ⇒ 0

Comment: I wondered if this would be an appropriate use case for a language model (e.g. BERT, but trained from scratch). I could take the embeddings for each word, then take a weighted average with the scores given above for a final document embedding, which could be used to train a binary classifier. I thought BERT would be more appropriate here than something like W2V because it captures context. Is this sound?

Comment: Could you explain the relevance of the tags you have chosen?  So far, nothing in your question concerns a Markov process, RNNs, word embeddings, language models, or even "sequence analysis" in the sense of that tag (which concerns genomic models).

Comment: The right method depends on the meaning of the these data. All you have told us is that you have four points in four-dimensional space, and your training set classifies them (assigns 0 or 1). Are the 0-marked points a continuous part of the space? If so, Gaussian Process Regression might work well. Or is there a reason you call these a "sequence"? There is no machine learning without prior knowledge.

Comment: @chrishmorris I'm not sure what you mean by "Are the 0-marked points a continuous part of the space?". Are you referring to the label, or the weight given to an element in the sequence? (e.g. `C (0.0)`)

Comment: @whuber it seemed appropriate to reach people from these communities who could provide a potential answer

Comment: Could you then at least supply some contextual or background information to help them understand what your data represent?